# I want to remove the Tool tip

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the tool tip, `"Do you really want to remove the agent?"` in my web application. The problem is that if I remove the tool tip, the content in the confirm dialog is also removed. I want to remove *only* the tool tip. The following is my code.

```
function remove(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var sessionEnterpriseId = '<%= session.getAttribute("enterpriseId")%>';
    var sessionRoleId = '<%= session.getAttribute("role")%>';

    if(sessionRoleId == 2) {
        if(rowObject.enterpriseId == sessionEnterpriseId) {
            return "<a href='javascript:confirmDelete("+ rowObject.id +")' ><img src='./images/remove.gif' title='Remove Agent'><div id='dialog-confirm' title='Remove Agent' style='display:none'> <p style='position: absolute; top: 20px; width: 303px;'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;'></span>Do you really want to remove the agent..?</p</div></a>";
        }
        else {
            return "<img src='./images/removeGray.gif' title='Remove Agent'>";
        }
    }
    else {
        return "<a href='javascript:confirmDelete("+ rowObject.id +")' ><img src='./images/remove.gif' title='Remove Agent' ><div id='dialog-confirm' title='Remove Agent' style='display:none'> <p style='position: absolute; top: 20px; width: 303px;'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;'></span>Do you really want to remove the agent..?</p></div> </a>";
    }
}

function confirmDelete ( a ) {  
    $(function() {      
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "YES": function() {
                    $(this).load("./removeAgent.action?id="+a,  function() {
                        $("#agentResult").trigger("reloadGrid");
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "   NO    ": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
             }
        });
    });
}
```

Help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want you" to edit title.

Comment: Could you post the rendered source since the asp is not relevant and provide a working example at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code: `</span>Do you really want to remove the agent..?</p</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax error, Line 7

`</p</div>`

This would cause your jQuery selector to fail.